# how to set initial value in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

could you please suggest how to set initial value in react ?
here is my code

http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/mPYzdw

```
class App extends React.Component{
  getInitialState(){
    return {data: 'test'};
  }

  render(){
    return <div>hello {this.state.data}</div>
  }

}

React.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See this post from the React blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html).

You set it in the constructor.

```
import {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: 'test'};
  }
  render() { ... }
}
```

Also, I notice you're using `React.render` which is no longer a thing.

```
import {render} from 'react-dom'

// ...
render(<App/>, document.getElementyById('app'));
```

Comment: @user944513 there are countless resources online. Just make sure you're studying something current as React changes somewhat frequently. I also read the React blog which does a terrific job of detailing those changes.